# Monitor Size Discrepancy causing Form Issues: Powershell vs ISE

Tags: forms, powershell, winforms, multiple-monitors

I have a variant of the below Form designed in Powershell. However, when I run it with ISE it pops up in a different size/resolution from the Powershell Console. I've been trying to control for this by dynamically adjusting the height/width of the different fonts and controls, but even when everything else adjusts properly, the [system.Windows.Forms.Label] control's font just doesn't adjust in line with everything else.

**On investigation, the applications seem to be picking up the Primary Screen in different resolutions, though the Secondary Screen is consistent for both. Why would the two applications be detecting different Primary Screen resolutions?**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
```

Powershell Output:

```
BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1368,Height=912}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY1
Primary      : True
WorkingArea  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1368,Height=882}
```

ISE Output:

```
BitsPerPixel : 32
Bounds       : {X=0,Y=0,Width=2736,Height=1824}
DeviceName   : \\.\DISPLAY1
Primary      : True
WorkingArea  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=2736,Height=1764}
```

### Form Code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$monitor = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen # PrimaryScreen producing inconsistent results between Powershell/ISE
$w  = $monitor.WorkingArea.Width / 2000
$h  = $monitor.WorkingArea.Height / 1200

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$validatorForm                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$validatorForm.Size           = New-Object 'System.Drawing.Size' (2020*$w), (1220*$h)
$validatorForm.text           = "Validator"
$validatorForm.BackColor      = "#D0E0F0"
$validatorForm.TopMost        = $true
$validatorForm.AutoScale      = $true

$FontLabel = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$(11*$w)"
$FontText  = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$(20*$w)"

$InputLabel                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$InputLabel.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((20*$w),(40*$h))
$InputLabel.width             = 635*$w
$InputLabel.height            = 40*$h
$InputLabel.Font              = $FontLabel
$InputLabel.ForeColor         = '#001166'
$InputLabel.text              = "Copy + Paste an AF Element into this text box:"

$userInput                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$userInput.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((660*$w),(40*$h))
$userInput.Font               = $FontText
$userInput.width              = 1320*$w
$userInput.height             = 40*$h
$userInput.text               = '\\ExampleServer\Database\Path'

$SubmitButton                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SubmitButton.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((660*$w),(130*$h))
$SubmitButton.width           = 400*$w
$SubmitButton.height          = 60*$h
$SubmitButton.Font            = $LabelText
$SubmitButton.Text            = "Run Validation"
$SubmitButton.BackColor       = "#BBDDBB"

$validatorForm.controls.AddRange(@($InputLabel,$userInput,$SubmitButton))
$validatorForm.AcceptButton = $SubmitButton

[system.windows.forms.application]::run($validatorForm)

$validatorForm                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$validatorForm.Size           = New-Object 'System.Drawing.Size' (2020*$w), (1220*$h)
$validatorForm.text           = "Validator"
$validatorForm.BackColor      = "#D0E0F0"
$validatorForm.TopMost        = $true
$validatorForm.AutoScale      = $true

$FontLabel = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$(11*$w)"
$FontText  = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$(20*$w)"

$InputLabel                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$InputLabel.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((20*$w),(40*$h))
$InputLabel.width             = 635*$w
$InputLabel.height            = 40*$h
$InputLabel.Font              = $FontLabel
$InputLabel.ForeColor         = '#001166'
$InputLabel.text              = "Copy + Paste an element into this text box:"

$userInput                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$userInput.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((660*$w),(40*$h))
$userInput.Font               = $FontText
$userInput.width              = 1320*$w
$userInput.height             = 40*$h
$userInput.text               = '\\ExampleServer\Database\Path'

$SubmitButton                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SubmitButton.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((660*$w),(130*$h))
$SubmitButton.width           = 400*$w
$SubmitButton.height          = 60*$h
$SubmitButton.Font            = $LabelText
$SubmitButton.Text            = "Run Validation"
$SubmitButton.BackColor       = "#BBDDBB"

$validatorForm.controls.AddRange(@($InputLabel,$userInput,$SubmitButton))
$validatorForm.AcceptButton = $SubmitButton

[system.windows.forms.application]::run($validatorForm)
```

Comment: Could not reproduce this. It's both the same size for me. Try breaking this down to the most minimal example. Maybe you'll even find the issue on the way.

Comment: @marsze - I thought this was fairly minimal! I have two monitors which have different resolutions, so one of my theories was that each application was picking up a different default resolution or something like that. Both pop the form open on the same screen, but the Consoles for the two application each have their own favourite monitor they start on.

Comment: @iRon - sorry, nope, I'd accidentally cut that line out of my cut-down example script above, but I had already tried it, and have just tried again to be safe.

Comment: @marsze - I've found the problem, but not sure what's causing it. Details now included in question. Why would the two applications be picking up different display resolutions for the Primary monitor (DISPLAY1)?

Comment: That's strange. Again, cannot reproduce. What values exactly do you get for each?

Comment: @marsze - have pasted the output of each into the question above. On checking windows settings, it looks like ISE is getting the "true" resolution as it shows on the Display Settings. However, since the display has extremely high DPI Windows is applying a 200% (Recommended) scale (Display >Scale and Layout). So perhaps PowerShell is picking up this pseudo resolution but not applying the scaling? Maybe if you change the scaling on your monitor it would reproduce?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I suppose these settings just don't apply to console apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure why the detected primary monitor resolution would be different between ISE/Powershell, but I found the source of the variant behaviour:

[image: Display Scale and Layout]

Due to the extremely high resolution of the primary monitor, it has an additional scaling parameter of 200%. So ISE seems to have detected the 'true' resolution of 2736x1824, where Powershell detected the pseudo resolution of 1368x912 but not the 200% scaling that it runs with to fill the display.

Though I couldn't properly detect or account for the scaling as I would have liked to, I've solved the sizing inconsistency for [system.Windows.Forms.Label], which is a suitable workaround for the behaviour. One surprising thing to note was that the Label font sizes are scaled automatically, so when I removed the manual scaling factor from $FontLabel it then scales correctly, though it still needed the scaling factor for $FontText:

```
$FontLabel = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$(11)"
$FontText  = "Microsoft Sans Serif,$(20*$w)"
```

So **by applying my scaling factors to everything except Label Fonts**, I was able to get the form to scale appropriately in both applications.